# Areas of two polygons with same centroid

Tags: geometry, convex-analysis, plane-geometry

Give a polygon $P$ in $\mathbb{R}^2$, the **centroid** of $P$ is $(v_1+\cdots+v_n)/n$, where $v_1,\ldots,v_n\in\mathbb{R}^2$ are the vertices of $P$.

Suppose $P$ and $Q$ are two polygons in $\mathbb{R}^2$ satisfies:

1. They have the same centroid.
2. The ratios of their shaows in every direction are at most $C$, i.e. for all line $l$ going through their centroid, $$length(l\cap P)/length(l\cap Q)\leq C.$$

**Claim:** The ratios of their areas is at most $C^2$.

Is the claim correct?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think this can be true.

Consider this figure:
[image]

Although this has circular segments, it can be approximated by a polygon.
Cuts through its centroid are almost all the same length, and if I did my calculations right, its area is $\frac{10}{9}$ times that of a circle with that diameter.

So here are two figures, which when approximated by polygons $P$ and $Q$, will have almost the same cut lengths through their centroid, but a distinctly different area.

If your polygons approximate them closely enough, $C$ will be close to $1$, and for sure you can get $C^2<\frac{10}{9}$, and construct a counterexample to your claim.

I think that even with convex polygons, a similar technique will result in a counterexample.